# Django & TastyPie: request.POST is empty

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm trying to do a POST using curl:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"item_id": "1"}' http://www.mylocal.com:8000/api/1/bookmarks/
```

However, request.POST is always empty.

Below is my ModelResource code:

```
class BookmarkResource(ModelResource):


    class Meta:
        queryset = Bookmark.objects.all()    
        resource_name = 'bookmarks'
        fields = ['id', 'tags']
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'delete', 'put']
        always_return_data = True
        authorization= Authorization()
        include_resource_uri = False

    def determine_format(self, request):
        return "application/json"

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):

        request = bundle.request

        try:
            payload = simplejson.loads(request.POST.keys()[0])
        except:
            payload = simplejson.loads(request.POST.keys())
```

Anybody knows what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Starting at Django 1.5, `request.POST` does not contain non-form data anymore. They are now in [`request.body`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body).

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208067/wheres-my-json-data-in-my-incoming-django-request.

Comment: @dannyroa What differentiates "form data" and "non-form data"?

Comment: ...Looking at Django source, it looks like it is defined in `_load_post_and_files()` and depends on the `CONTENT_TYPE` -- `multipart/form-data` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a cURL expect but copying a POST request out of Chrome dev tools my `--data` looked as follows:

`--data "foo=bar&bar=foo"`

So it looks like you might want to change your command to:

`--data item_id="1"`

**Side note:**
I can highly recommend either of the following Chrome apps for making HTTP requests:

[Advanced REST client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) OR [Dev HTTP Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dev-http-client/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm?utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher)

Additionally if you can make the call in a browser (form submit or such like) then in Chrome dev tools network panel you can copy the request as a cURL command (right click on it)

Comment: Have you tried pdb/ipdb to see what is available on `request`?

Comment: Yeah, I used ipdb to trace through it. On the REST Client, I set the Content-Type to "application/json".

Comment: Weird thing is sometimes it goes to request.GET. I made sure I was doing a POST.

Comment: `'{"item_id": "1"}'` is available on bundle.request.body if that helps.  Will keep digging.

Comment: You are right. Is this something that changed recently for Django on how it handles request?

Comment: Looks like this is a change related to Django 1.5. request.POST does not contain non-form data anymore. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST

Comment: Ahh good catch.  Also if you're simply mapping json to the model then you don't need to create a `obj_create` method.

Comment: Actually, I had to override the create method. I get an item_id and access another API before creating the object.