# django tastypie - Post request tests are not working

Tags: python, django, tastypie, django-tests

I am trying to create a POST api using tastypie. It is working fine when I am running from postman. But when I created django tests for the same, the data is not coming in `request.POST` instead it is coming in `request.body`. Is there a way to test it similar to postman using django tests? I know it is coming in `request.body` but why is it working from postman? I followed this(https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/testing.html) also but same issue.

api.py

```
class CustResource(Resource):
    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'customer'
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/register%s$" %
                (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()),
                self.wrap_view('register_me'), name="api_register_me")
                ]

    def register_me(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])
        self.is_authenticated(request)

        response = {"status": 'error', 'data':{'error_code': '9999'},
                'message':'some issue'}

        return self.create_response(request, response)
```

tests.py

```
class RestApiTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        """
        create
        """
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(username="anuj",email="anuj@gmail.com",password="testing")
        self.apikey = ApiKey.objects.get(user=self.user)

    def test1(self):
        """
        """
        client = Client()
        json_str = json.dumps({'format':'json','username':'anuj','api_key':'fc32bd921bb6386c945229e675704818b29dadf0'})
        response = client.post('/api/v1/customer/register/',data=json_str, content_type='application/json')
        print response.status_code
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200, msg="Wrong status code")
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213324/django-tastypie-request-post-is-empty

Comment: Can you suggest a way to test post request using Django tests i.e. Send json data in as form data?