# What is wrong with my javascript fetch API call?

Tags: javascript, django, fetch-api

I have a javascript fetch API call made to a Django backend server

```
const res = fetch(url, {
  credentials: 'include',
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'same-origin',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
  })
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseJson) => {
    return responseJson.movies;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

If I output the requestBody on the console before using it in the request, it looks like follows

```
{"add-Choice":["L"],"add-Left":["1"],"add-Right":["1"],"add-Value":["100"],"add-match":["8"],"user":["siteuser1"],"csrfmiddlewaretoken":["3K89ZvofjhIL2nZQoCcxphjmXborujsaLPn2FzlYiVmiBLODWhQQiAB5BhSXkQcF"],"add":["Submit"]}
```

Here string "add-" is used as a form prefix on the Django side view post methode.
However, on the server view side, if I print the request.POST as follow

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print('Post request: ', request.POST)
```

I get the output as an empty QueryDict as follow

```
Post request:  <QueryDict: {}>
Internal Server Error: /matchoffers/8
```

The request is being sent to the correct URL and is picked up the correct view-post methode. But it fails because the request is empty.

Comment: I suspect `requestBody` is already JSON, you don't need to stringify it again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django & TastyPie: request.POST is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213324/django-tastypie-request-post-is-empty)

Comment: @Ivar That was correct pointer. However, there was a slight problem with the accepted answer on that page. The data was present in request.body. However, I was having problems with accessing that data. There was some error saying that you cannot access body after reading from request's data stream. I was able to access the form data through request.data. Long story short, if you are using fetch api with form data inside fetch->body, then use request.data on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you're doing REST-based web service stuff ... you should ignore
> request.POST.
>
> ```
> — Malcom Tredinnick, Django developers group
> ```

[Just in case you are using DRF and you forgot to tell us](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/)

Comment: Used request.data to access my form data in the fetch->body.

Comment: Dude! I lost the bounty what did you take you so long :D I'm glad to hear that. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Bane of all the developers. War room meeting. Sorry about that.