# Django Views not getting POST Data from api call

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am not using django rest frame work

but in normal views.py I have a simple views

#views.py

```
def api_post_operations(request):
    pdb.set_trace()
    if request.POST:
        print(request.POST["name"])
        print(request.POST["address"])
```

now I call it

```
import requests
url = "http://localhost:8000/api_post_operations"
payload = {"name":"raj", "address": "asasass" }
rees = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers={})
```

it is comming

```
(Pdb) request.POST
<QueryDict: {}>
```

Any reason why it is comming {} balnk

```
request.body also comming blank
```

Comment: maybe helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213324/django-tastypie-request-post-is-empty

Comment: Also maybe headers should be multipart/form-data or application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: request.body also come b''